# Attempted to solve python problem, but have encountered an error

Tags: python

The question is:

> Write a function cad_cashier(price, payment) that takes two real nonnegative numbers with two decimal places as input, where payment>=price and where the second decimal in payment is 0 or 5. They represent a price and payment in Canadian dollars. The function should return a real number with 2 decimal places representing the change the customer should get in Canadian dollars. Recall that in Canada, while the prices are expressed in pennies, the change is based on rounding to the closest 5 cents.

What I have tried:

```py
def cad_cashier(price, payment):
    
    if not (price.is_integer() and payment.is_integer()):
        return "Invalid input: Price and payment must have two decimal places."
    
    change_in_pennies = int((payment - price) * 100)

    change_in_pennies = round(change_in_pennies / 5) * 5

    change_in_dollars = change_in_pennies / 100

    return round(change_in_dollars, 2)
```

This gives following output:

```
>>> cad_cashier(10.58,11)
'Invalid input: Price and payment must have two decimal places.'
```

When I input this, I want it to get me 0.4. What exactly do I need to fix?

Comment: What does "where the second decimal in payment is 0 or 5" mean? Example? Also, if you pass 11 that will be an int type which does not have an is_integer attribute

Answer (score 0):

the method `is_integer` will return `FALSE` for nonintegers. 10.58 is not an integer, that's why you get the error message. see https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/float/is_integer.html

you have to find a function that allows doubles with 2 decimal places.
to solve your problem you may look at [Limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code:

```py
if not (price.is_integer() and payment.is_integer()):
    return "Invalid input: Price and payment must have two decimal places."
```

Checks if both the price and the payment are integers. I think what you were trying to do was to check if both had up to two decimal places. You could just remove this from your code and have:

```py
def cad_cashier(price, payment):
    change_in_pennies = int((payment - price) * 100)

    change_in_pennies = round(change_in_pennies / 5) * 5

    change_in_dollars = change_in_pennies / 100

    return round(change_in_dollars, 2)
```

but if you really want to check your inputs, you could probably use something like `round()` or `math.trunc()`:

```py
if round(price, 2) != price or round(payment, 2) != payment or payment < price:
    print("Invalid input!")
    return
```

Comment: You can check if a value has no more than 2 decimal places by multiplying it by 100.0 and testing is_integer()

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your parameters are both float. You can do that within the function although it would be better to pass float values.

You need to check that there are *no more than* 2 decimals specified. For example, if you pass 11 then that implicitly has two decimal places (of zero) whereas 9.995 would be invalid.

The payment amount needs to be larger than the price.

Then you can do this:

```
def cad_cashier(price, payment):
    def isvalid(x):
        return (x * 100.0).is_integer()
    if isvalid(price) and isvalid(payment) and payment > price:
        return round((payment - price) * 20) / 20

if (change := cad_cashier(10.58, 11)) is not None:
    print(f'Change = ${change:.2f}')
else:
    print('Invalid parameters')
```

**Output:**

```
Change = $0.40
```